# Two finite positive measures are mutually singular if and only if their minimum is zero.

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\mu$ and $v$ be two finite positive measures on a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{B})$. Prove that $\mu \perp v \iff \mu + v = |\mu - v|$

For the forward direction, I think I need to use the Jordan decomposition theorem, particularly the uniqueness. For the backwards, I am not sure.

Let $\rho = \mu - v$ be a signed measure. Then by uniqueness, as we have $\mu \perp v$, it follows that $\rho_{+} = \mu$ and $\rho_{-} = v$. How do I proceed?

Here is a similar question: [Two finite positive measures are singular iff a condition is satisfied](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3936259/two-finite-positive-measures-are-singular-iff-a-condition-is-satisfied?rq=1)

Comment: What does $\min(u,v)$ here mean? In particular, take Lebesgue measure and delta function at 0 for interval $[0,1]$. Is this not a counter example?

Comment: @Pig $min(u, v) = \frac{1}{2} (\mu+ v - |\mu - v|)$

Comment: Thanks! I think my point still stands - Lebesgue measure and delta function at 0 for $[0,1]$ are mutually singular, but the minimum is not 0.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure is not finite though

Comment: What do you mean by finite measure then? On $[0,1]$ I think Lebesgue measure is finite ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what the delta function means. It is this question on stackexchange: 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319738/two-positive-measures-are-mutually-singular-iff-their-sum-is-the-variation-of-th

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood what absolute value means, thanks.

Comment: In that case, by definition of absolute value of measure - $|\mu - \nu| = \mu + \nu$ when $\mu \perp \nu$. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Note that $|\mu - \nu|$ here must mean the total variation of the signed measure $\mu-\nu$.  In particular it is possible for the minimum of two measures to be zero even if neither of the two is the zero measure (otherwise the claim would trivially be false), so your backward direction is not correct.

Comment: @Pig Apologies, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Radon-Nykodim there exists $h$ such that
$d(\mu-\nu)=hd(|\mu-\nu|)=hd(\mu+\nu)$.
This implies $(1-h)d\mu=(h+1)d\nu$. Since $|h|=1$ $\mu+\nu$-a.e.  wlog we can suppose that $|h|=1$ everywhere.   Now let $A=h^{-1}(1),B=h^{-1}(-1)$. Then $\nu_{|A}\equiv 0, \mu_{|B}\equiv 0$ and $X=A\cup B$, proving that the two measures are mutually singular.

For the other direction, let $A,B$ be complementary sets on which $\mu,\nu$ are respectively supported and let $h:=\chi_{A}-\chi_B
$
.  Now,$d|\mu-\nu|\ge hd(\mu-\nu)=d(\mu+\nu)\ge d|\mu-\nu$ and the result follows

Comment: Is there a simpler proof? So far, we have only done Jordan Decomposition and Hahn Decomposition, no Radon-Nykodim yet.

Comment: @John the only part in which R.N. was used was to prove the statement "there exists $h$ such that $d(\mu-\nu)=hd|\mu-\nu|$. This can be proved directly with the Hahn Decomposition: 
in general, take $\sigma$ a finite signed measure. We can write $\sigma=\sigma^+-\sigma^-,|\sigma|=\sigma^++\sigma^-$, where $\sigma^+\perp\sigma^-$. Just take $h$ to be $1$ on the support of $\sigma^+$ and $-1$ on the support of $\sigma^-$ and you get $d\sigma=hd|\sigma|$